# Upload and Rename File Plugin in Mooddle

Tags: php, file, plugins, upload, moodle

I'm really new to Mooddle development and I'm not really sure how to achieve this, but if someone can give me a hand I would really appreciate it.

What I'm trying to do is to "clone" the file upload plugin and make a new one that does exactly the same but also rename the file. The purpose for this is that teachers need to upload the course roadmap, but some of them just don't do it; so the person that manages all the courses needs to be able to check in the DB what teacher uploaded it and what teacher didn't.

The idea is to have a dedicated button called "course roadmap" for example, and have the teacher upload it through this button, and since not all teachers name the file the same, i would like to rename the file to, for example, "roadmap_design", "roadmap_law", "roadmap_architecture", and so on, being the word "roadmap_" placed at the beginning of every file.

I'm using Moodle 3.0 and the Essential Theme. I'm not sure where to find the plugin source code to duplicate it and edit it for a new plugin. And how can I install this new plugin?

Hope this is possible and that someone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All file related stuff handles by plugins is done by "repositories"
https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Repository_plugins should get you started. You can clone /repository/upload, but note that you have to update several files and classnames (see Creating new repository plugin) in the documentation above.

Once you have your clone running, you can adapt the upload routine here to reach your renamings

Unfortunately i cannot attach files, please fined attached my "cloned" upload2 directory. You can download it on [wetransfer](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/3c6b33ee52d0707c5b4f9360bf56ce5620170120090017/384d88)

[image]

Comment: Hi Bearzi, thanks for your reply! I've been looking over the files in the repositories but cant seem to find the code for the File Module for me to clone and make my own plugin. When I enter the "Add an activity or resource" inside a course, I get a list of options, what I need to do is to clone the "File" module and make a new one that renames the file the user uploads. I cant seem to figure out how to do this with the files I found in the repositories folder. There is one folder called "uplaod" but its not the same as the File Module. Your help is really appreciated, I'm kind of lost. Thanks

Comment: Heya, see edit of my post above, hope it helps? The repository itself is seen once you get a "choose file" dialog. If you want to clone the "Add an activity" and have "File" here, you will have to create a "Activity Module", not a file repository, but repository is defintely easier for your purposes